# How to find out a specific character is present in a NSString or not?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I have two NSStrings named country and searchtext. I need to check whether the country contains the searchtext.

Eg: country = Iceland and searchtext = c, here the word iceland contains the character 'c'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSRange range = [country rangeOfString:searchtext];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
}
```

You also have the position (location) and length of your match (uninteresting in this case but might be interesting in others) in your range object. Note that `searchtext` must not be `nil`. If you are only interested in matching (and not the location) you can even condense this into

```
if ([country rangeOfString:searchtext].location != NSNotFound)
{
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
NSString *st =    @"Iceland";
NSString *t_st = @"c";      
NSRange rang =[st rangeOfString:t_st options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

   if (rang.length == [t_st length]) 
   {
          NSLog(@"done");
   }
   else
   {
          NSLog(@"not done");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple... try this

```
-(BOOL)doesString:(NSString *)string containCharacter:(char)character
{
    if ([string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```